# Is there a way to execute text gremlin query with PartitionStrategy

Tags: tinkerpop, gremlinpython

I'm looking for an implementation to run text query ex: "g.V().limit(1).toList()" while using the PatitionStrategy in Apache TinkerPop.

I'm attempting to build a REST interface to run queries on selected graph paritions only. I know how to run a raw query using Client, but I'm looking for an implementation where I can create a multi-tenant graph (https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#partitionstrategy) and query only selected tenants using raw text query instead of a GLV. Im able to query only selected partitions using pythongremlin, but there is no reference implementation I could find to run a text query on a tenant.
Here is tenant query implementation

```
connection = DriverRemoteConnection('ws://megamind-ws:8182/gremlin', 'g')
g = traversal().withRemote(connection)
partition = PartitionStrategy(partition_key="partition_key",
                          write_partition="tenant_a",
                          read_partitions=["tenant_a"])
partitioned_g = g.withStrategies(partition)
x = partitioned_g.V.limit(1).next() <---- query on partition only
```

Here is how I execute raw query on entire graph, but Im looking for implementation to run text based queries on only selected partitions.

```
from gremlin_python.driver import client

client = client.Client('ws://megamind-ws:8182/gremlin', 'g')


results = client.submitAsync("g.V().limit(1).toList()").result().one() <-- runs on entire graph.
print(results)
client.close()
```

Any suggestions appreciated? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how the backend store handles text mode queries, but for the query itself, essentially you just need to use the Groovy/Java style formulation. This will work with GremlinServer and Amazon Neptune. For other backends you will need to make sure that this syntax is supported. So from Python you would use something like:

```java
client.submit('
  g.withStrategies(new PartitionStrategy(partitionKey: "_partition", 
                                         writePartition: "b", 
                                         readPartitions: ["b"])).V().count()')
```